# Google Map api 3 zoom

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am using Google map 3 API.
I am having a problem in Google map, where I want to display one marker in the entire map, if I am trying to fit the bounds based on the latitude longitude of this point, starting display is coming to the max. Can someone suggest any best solution for this one?

Comment: Can you show us some code what you have up to now?

Answer (score 0):

You want to show only one marker, then why fit bounds? This should do-

```
map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
```

also

```
//you can set a zoom level like `map.setZoom(6);`
```

---

**Update:**

While placing your marker analyze whether it is one or more. I don't think this should be tough. Since you haven't provided any code, cant exactly point the location. If it is going to be more than one-

```
if(number of markers to be placed > 1 )
{
   bounds.extend(marker.getLocation());
   map.fitBounds(bounds);
}
else //markers to be placed is only one 
{
   map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
}
```

---

Incase the distance between two markers is very less and you donot want to zoom that high,
a simple solution is using `maxZoom` property of the map. Simply set this value when you create your map. So you never go beyond that zoom level.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. My problem is the number of markers on the page is dynamic. So the display is coming bad when there is only one marker or if more than one markers are here in a very small distance.

Comment: See the update. Providing your code would have been easier to help

Comment: for(var i=0;i<recordsPerPage;i++){
 latitude=null;
 longitude=null;
 latitude=getElementValue("latitude"+i);
 longitude=getElementValue("longitude"+i);
 if(some condition){
  list[i]=new google.maps.LatLng(latitude,longitude);
  latlngbounds.extend(list[i]);
  marker[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
   position : list[i],
   icon: "https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/marker" + markerTitleList[i] + ".png",
   map : map
  });
  marker[i].setTitle(setAddressOnPlaceMarker(i));
 }
 map.setCenter(latlngbounds.getCenter()); 
 map.fitBounds(latlngbounds); 
}

Comment: I understand you are a new user. You can put the code in your question by editing it which is better to read.

Comment: This solution will work if only one marker is present. But if two markers are there in a nominal distance, suppose in same building, this condition will fail

Comment: See the updated answer, that should resolve all your issues :)